# scheduling crontab without kerberos

Tags: linux, hive, cron, cloudera, impala

Trying to schedule the `cron` tab job from Linux.When i try it execute the shell script(Impala and hive commands) manually,it ran successfully but it was failing when i schedule it from `crontab`

```
* * * * * sh /path/example.sh
```

> Error : valid kerberos ticket but no valid kerberos ticket found.

Is the `keytab` is mandatory for the user ? 
Do we need to include the `keytab` in `script` ?
With out key tab can we schedule the job from crontab ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Kerberos is enabled, you need a keytab/ticket to run Impala and Hive commands.  Ideally, you should kinit the keytab inside the script.

Comment: created keytab and added inside the script, still having issues
kinit -kt XXXXX.keytab

Comment: Do a klist after the kinit to see that your ticket is valid.